# Has SOAP exclusively used HTTP POST historically for HTTP?

Tags: http, post, soap

Has SOAP exclusively used HTTP POST historically? In other words, does SOAP mainly use HTTP POST for all types of request? In comparison, the RESTful approach may be to use request types closely matching the purpose of the message. I wondered what the current and historical stance has been for SOAP.

Comment: [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) does not define which transport to use. HTTP is the most commonly used one (historically and present), but SOAP messages can be transmitted using JMS, SMTP, TCP or other transport protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP mainly considers the use of HTTP POST historically (though can use other protocols such as SMTP) for request and response since version 1.1. However, since version 1.2 it can use GET requests with no SOAP message receiving a SOAP response. (Papazoglou, Michael P. (2008). Web Services: Principles and Technology. Harlow: Pearson Education Limited. p140-143.)